# SHGetKnownFolderPath / Environment.GetFolderPath() returning wrong value for public documents

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-7, .net-4.0, known-folders

I got a somewhat strange error when trying to resolve the `CommonDocuments` directory. 
It keeps resolving to the wrong directory, after the CommonDocuments directory has been **redirected / moved** to a new location using Windows Explorer (Properties->Path from the context menu).

a minimal working piece of code would be:

```
namespace CommonDocumentsTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly Guid CommonDocumentsGuid = new Guid("ED4824AF-DCE4-45A8-81E2-FC7965083634");

        [Flags]
        public enum KnownFolderFlag : uint
        {
            None = 0x0,
            CREATE = 0x8000,
            DONT_VERFIY = 0x4000,
            DONT_UNEXPAND= 0x2000,
            NO_ALIAS = 0x1000,
            INIT = 0x800,
            DEFAULT_PATH = 0x400,
            NOT_PARENT_RELATIVE = 0x200,
            SIMPLE_IDLIST = 0x100,
            ALIAS_ONLY = 0x80000000
        }

        [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rfid, uint dwFlags, IntPtr hToken, out IntPtr pszPath);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            KnownFolderFlag[] flags = new KnownFolderFlag[] {
                KnownFolderFlag.None,
                KnownFolderFlag.ALIAS_ONLY | KnownFolderFlag.DONT_VERFIY,
                KnownFolderFlag.DEFAULT_PATH | KnownFolderFlag.NOT_PARENT_RELATIVE,
            };


            foreach (var flag in flags)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}; P/Invoke==>{1}", flag, pinvokePath(flag)));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string pinvokePath(KnownFolderFlag flags)
        {
            IntPtr pPath;
            SHGetKnownFolderPath(CommonDocumentsGuid, (uint)flags, IntPtr.Zero, out pPath); // public documents

            string path = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pPath);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pPath);
            return path;
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected behaviour:**
Output is `D:\TestDocuments`

**Actual behaviour:**
Output is `C:\Users\Public\Documents`

> None; P/Invoke==>C:\Users\Public\Documents
>   DONT_VERFIY, ALIAS_ONLY; P/Invoke==>
>   NOT_PARENT_RELATIVE, DEFAULT_PATH; P/Invoke==>C:\Users\Public\Documents

The correct value is stored in the Windows Registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Common Documents), but it is not returned by `SHGetKnownFolderPath` (or `Environment.GetFolderPath`)

OS: Windows 7 Professional x64
.NET Framework v4.0.30319 
Application is compiled for **x86 CPU**

What I tried so far:

- restarting my application
- restarting the computer
- calling `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments);`
- direct calls to Win32-API SHGetKnownFolderPath

---

**EDIT 2**
Steps to reproduce:

1. deactivate UAC on your computer [and restart!]
2. go to C:\Users\Public\
3. right click on "Public Documents" folder and select
   `Properties`
4. select the 'Path' tab
5. click 'Move...' and select a (new) folder on drive `D:` called `TestDocuments`
6. click 'Apply'
7. accept to move all files to the new location start the minimal
   application above

Comment: I suspect that redirecting/moving it isn't properly done... usually such a change would be done through some Group Policy... and there is also the aspect of "localization" (the real folder has a different name than is displayed) which seems to play a role in your case...

Comment: The second line above where you combine EXPORT_REPOSITORY and "\\excel2007" will most likely give you a value of "\excel2007". At least according to documentation which states that "If path2 contains an absolute path, this method returns path2".

Comment: @Daniel thanks for pointing this out. I must have introduced that error on my local system - according to the versioning system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function for getting localized path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692425/function-for-getting-localized-path)

Comment: Am I missing something here? Why are you P/Invoking instead of using `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments`?

Comment: @SpikeX Please have a look at the history of this question. What you are suggesting was my first try and I've since been trying to get to the core of the problem.

Comment: Then from what it sounds like, the problem does not lie with this variable, instead, with how the user moved their documents folder. I suspect some value or some registry entry isn't getting updated somewhere, not to mention, some folders inside the C:\Users\ structure are junctions (not real folders), so moving them only moves the junction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Behaviour is by design and only appears when you're running an assembly that was compiled for **x86 CPUs** on a x64 OS

---

**Longer version:**
`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments)` accesses the 32-bit hive of the Windows Registry.
The actual path to the folder is stored in the 64-bit hive. 
The issue has been forwarded to the Windows team and may be fixed in a future version of Windows.

For a bit more information see [the Microsoft connect report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/686394/possible-bug-in-environment-getfolderpath-shgetknownfolderpath-with-redirected-public-documents-folder)

---

**Workaround**
create a console application with the following code and compile it for **ANY CPU**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments));
}
```

then call it from your main application:

```
Process proc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("myConsoleApp.exe");

// allow output to be read
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo = info;

proc.Start(); 
proc.WaitForExit();
string path = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

this will launch the **ANY CPU** executable, which only prints out the desired path to the standard output. The output then is read in the main application and you get the real path.